# NodeJS Sequelize - Multiple Ownership

Tags: node.js, orm, dao, sequelize.js

In my application I have Users and Contacts. Users make ContactRequests to other Users. The ContactRequest has a requester and requestee field. I don't know how to go about this. I don't want a Users, ContactRequests, and ContactRequestsUsers table (as sequelize would if I defined a hasMany or hasOne on both Users and ContactRequests).

So let me start by defining some models-

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {type: seq.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    username: {
        type: sequelize.STRING(32)
    }
});

var ContactRequest = sequelize.define('ContactRequest', {
    id: {type: seq.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true}
});
```

Not sure what associations I should make. It seems like I should be able to do this several ways (in theory) but I can't get any of the ways I've tried to work.

```
// User Has Many?
User.hasMany(ContactRequest, {as: 'Requester', foreignKey: 'requester'});
User.hasMany(ContactRequest, {as: 'Requestee', foreignKey: 'requestee'});

// ContactRequest Belongs to?
ContactRequest.belongsTo(User, {});

// Experience Has One?
ContactRequest.hasOne(User, {as: 'Requester'});
ContactRequest.hasOne(User, {as: 'Requestee'});
```

With each variation I've tried different methods to checking to see if userA has made a ContactRequest to userB.

```
// Checking if a user has a contact request?

var userA = 'someuser1';
var userB = 'someuser2';

ContactRequest.find({where: {'Requester.username': userA, 'Requestee.username': userB}, include: [{model: User, as: 'Requester'}, {model: User, as: 'Requestee'}]}).success(function(cr) {
    console.log(cr);
});

// Maybe by the user?

User.find({where: {username: userA}}).success(function(someuser) {
    someuser.getRequestee({where: {'Requestee.username': userB}, include: [{model: User, as: 'Requestee'}]}).success(function(cr) {
        console.log(cr);
    });
});
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong but I can't get this to work. Any help or foresight would be appreciated.